# how to check a value in multiple rows in mysql table associated with a unique data in each row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a record management application using php. I've designed a table named records with fields `id`, `recordname`, `recordvalue`, `recordid`. For example if a record consists of 3 data `firstname`, `lastname`, `gender`. 3 data (John Doe Male, Jane Doe Female and Sherlcok Holmes Male) is inserted in the table as below-

```
----+-------------+--------------+-----------
id  | recordname  | recordvalue  | recordid
----+-------------+--------------+-----------
1   | firstname   | John         | 001
2   | lastname    | Doe          | 001
3   | gender      | Male         | 001
4   | firstname   | Jane         | 002  
5   | lastname    | Doe          | 002
6   | gender      | Female       | 002
7   | firstname   | Sherlock     | 003
8   | lastname    | Holmes       | 003
9   | gender      | Male         | 003

----+-------------+--------------+-----------
```

my question is when i'm going to insert a new record in the table i need to check if there is any duplication of the record. That means any field for different records can be duplicated anytime but all the fields having same values for a  record can't be duplicated. From previous example records having value John Doe Female, Jane Doe Male, Sherlock Doe Male etc are OK but again inserting John Doe Male is not expected and it'll give an error.

How can i achieve this easily with PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i cant understand your database structure, why you are storing different records for firstname,lastname and gender

Comment: Is there a reason you are using this approach (generally known as Entity-Attributte-Value; EAV for short) to your table structure? It's generally less suitable to use with relational databases than more conventional, normalised data structures.

Comment: @MarkBannister i cant understand why he using this type of structure

Comment: @maksbd19 first learn how to normalize the table

Comment: @YadavChetan: In the absence of further information, neither can I, although there are certain circumstances where this approach is suitable - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model .

Comment: Thanks everyone. I've designed my DB this way because there may be different number of record names in my application and admin can specify the number. I'm relatively new so expect your suggestions. Thanks again.

Comment: You can create a stored procedure to pivot your `recordname`s and `recordvalue`s values. Something like [in this sql fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4078d/1), then you can put these results in a temp table or from php test if there is any records having the same values.

Comment: In which case, definitely look at medina's answer, and also look into http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization .

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Thanks for you afford. I need to check the values only while inserting the data in the DB so that there is no duplication of same record (which will consist of several record names and values). Thanks.

Comment: Please stop complaining about normalization... this structure is intended for his purpose ...

Comment: maksbd - I have updated my answer to include a suggestion for a hybrid relational/EAV schema.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should fix your table, It has a really bad design. It should be something like that

```
table
--------------------------------------------
record_id | firstname | lastname | gender
```

and then you could use a UNIQUE INDEX (firstname, lastname, gender) to control that, if you wanted to keep it on only in your database.

**[EDIT]**

Due to the fact you can not change the database design and it is using EAV structure, you can use the query below to achieve what you are looking for. This query is gonna return if there is or not records based in your criteria.

```
SELECT a.recordvalue, b.recordvalue, c.recordvalue
FROM rec_eav a
INNER JOIN rec_eav b ON (b.recordid = a.recordid AND b.recordname = 'lastname' )
INNER JOIN rec_eav c ON (c.recordid = a.recordid AND c.recordname = 'gender' )
WHERE a.recordname = 'firstname' 
    AND a.recordvalue = 'John'
    AND b.recordvalue = 'Doe'
    AND c.recordvalue = 'Male'
```

Comment: Thanks @medina but i had an unique id for each record names recordid which i used to keep track of the fields in a single record set. What i need to check is while i submit a form, the values submitted from the form all not are same from another record which s already in the database, if any match is found then it'll return an error. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry for commenting again. I really needed to design an EAV model as attributes are unknown to me. They are set by the admin only. I do understand what you have suggested but it is not what i was looking for. I can not change my database design. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Hey mate, I understand your pain with EAV. I work with Magento every single day and I know just too well how it is like. Anyway, check out the Edition I've done in my comment. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> my question is when i'm going to insert a new record in the table i need to check if there is any duplication of the record.

Your “records” are something different than a normal database record (= one row) here.

> That means any field for different records can be duplicated anytime but all the fields having same values for a record can't be duplicated. From previous example records having value John Doe Female, Jane Doe Male, Sherlock Doe Male etc are OK but again inserting John Doe Male is not expected and it'll give an error.

So the combination of several records has to be unique in your case.

> How can i achieve this easily with PHP?

You could SELECT first and see if you get a result for the data to be inserted already, as Yadav suggested in his answer. But that will result in a possible TOCTTOU problem – to avoid that, you will have to encapsulate SELECT and INSERT into a transaction.

The other way would be to use an INSERT … SELECT statement. The SELECT statement must be formulated in a way that it only returns values to insert if it does *not* find them already – counting the matching records and using HAVING to filter for only those that give the right number of records (three in your example) would do that.

Comment: Thanks for your explained answer. Can you please give an example of your idea?

Answer (score 0):

Run a query similar to the following:

```
select count(*) countmatch
from datatable
where concat(recordname,':',recordvalue) in
      ('firstname:John', 'lastname:Doe', 'gender:Male')
group by recordid
order by countmatch desc
limit 1
```

- if the countmatch value returned is 3, reject the new John Doe Male record, otherwise add it to the table.

EDIT: If firstname, lastname and gender together uniquely identify a record, but the other attributes may be sparsely and/or arbitrarily populated, then you may want to consider a hybrid schema - possibly something like this:

```
KeyTable
--------
firstname
lastname
gender
recordid
```

- with a unique index on the combination of firstname, lastname and gender, and a separate unique index on recordid.

```
DataTable
---------
```

- as now, with a foreign key on recordid. Note that the firstname, lastname and gender attributes should **not** be stored on this table.

When trying to add "new" combinations of firstname, lastname and gender, try adding them to the KeyTable - if the insert is rejected by the DBMS, it means that the record already exists.

In this scenario, recordname/recordvalue combinations stored on DataTable should always include a recordid that links to a valid recordid on KeyTable.

Comment: This is phenomonally innefficient. It requires a additional SELECT before each INSERT, it requires interpolation of each row before the data can be checked, it ensures that you can't actually use any indexes to spped the query, and it undermines the one benefit of this schema - where representing attributes as rows instead of columns gives the possibility of adding multiple arbitrary attributes.

Comment: @symcbean: I assume you are the downvoter? Any compound key check in an EAV-based SQL DBMS system is going to require a SELECT before each INSERT, the interpolation of the rows (by which I assume you mean the concatenation of fields) is trivial compared to the rest of the processing, and multiple `(recordname='firstname' and recordvalue='John') or ...` conditions will also mean that you can't use indexes. These are some of the reasons why it is generally a bad idea to use an EAV schema with an RDBMS.

Comment: @symcbean: Also, this query does nothing to undermine the ability to add multiple arbitrary attributes.

Comment: (The hybrid schema suggested in my Edit would explicitly restrict the ability to add **key** attributes, but not **non-key** attributes.)

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like this:

```
SELECT a.recordid
FROM test a
JOIN test b ON ( b.recordname = 'firstname' AND b.recordvalue = 'John' AND b.recordid = a.recordid)
JOIN test c ON ( c.recordname = 'lastname' AND c.recordvalue = 'Doe' AND c.recordid = a.recordid)
WHERE (a.recordname = 'gender' AND a.recordvalue = 'female')
```

If the result is empty, then you can proceed (like in my example, if you change gender value to male it will return a recordid therefore this combination already exists)

Comment: Thanks @Xavjer I think i'm gonna need something like you have given. Can you please explain it a little? Thanks.

Comment: It's not that hard, just create a join for each recordname/value pair you have and connect it with the recordid, the last recordname/value pair can be in the WHERE clause (you could even create one more join and use no where statement). If the combination exists, it will return you the recordid of the duplicate record

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following query, if an answer is returned, then you already have similar data. If not, it will return 0 rows:

```
select recordid from records 
where recordvalue in ('John', 'Doe', 'Male')
group by recordid
having count(recordid) = 3
```

EDIT: Above query might give more than 1 result, as explained by @Xavjer, try this:

```
select * from 
(
select 
max(case when recordname="firstname" then recordvalue end) as firstname,
max(case when recordname="lastname" then recordvalue end) as lastname,
max(case when recordname="gender" then recordvalue end) as gender,
recordid
from records
group by recordid
) as record
where firstname='doe'
and lastname='john'
and gender='male'
```

Comment: I first tought that this would be a better solution than mine, but with this you will get a problem if there is a field which can have the same values (Like if we have a person named Nelson Quinn, and an other called Quinn Nelson)

Comment: You are right. I didn't guess that case. But even then I would not like to use `JOINS` in this case because number of records will always be humongous. I have edited my answer and included another way. But I agree with @medina, this begs for better schema design.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use an EAV model to store data then consider a structure like this:

```
eav_hell(entity*,attribute*,value) 

* = (component of) PRIMRY KEY
```

And spare a thought for the poor discarded data types.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your affords. Anyway I've found a solution of my problem. Its tricky and I don't know how efficient it is. So that I'm posting it here for expert's comments. Thanks.

My problem was- I have a EAV table where single entity has multiple attributes and corresponding values. I needed to check if anyone submits a form with some values of a record, all those are already in the database as another record. E.g. if John Doe Male is already in the table under `recordid` 001 then user can not save John Doe Male as another record, rather it'll give the user a message "Record already exists!".

I performed some queries -

```
foreach($submitted_values as $name => $value){
    $r = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `recordid` FROM `records` WHERE `recordname` = '$name' AND `recordvalue` = '$value'");                
    while($row  = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)){
        $assoc[$name][] = $row['recordid']; 
    }
}
```

so in `$assoc` i got an 2 dimensional array indexed with field names and associated with an array of matched `recordid` each.

Then I checked if there are any matched value in the `$assoc` array and if i get a non empty array that i'm sure that there one or many duplication of the submitted values under a single record.

This process helped me also tell the user that there are some partial matches of values. And it worked for me perfectly.

Again thanks everyone for wasting your valuable times.